# Instalación de Flask con pip python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip

Estoy intentando instalar Flask con `pip install flask`, pero al intentar descargarlo me da este error que dejo como imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error se da ya que durante Abril del 2018 [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/) migró de pypi.python.org a pypi.org. Esto significa que los comandos "trusted-host" que usan el dominio anterior ya no funcionan.

Puede ignorar los errores de SSL indicando pypi.org y files.pythonhosted.org como "hosts de confianza".

```
$ pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>
```

Si desea que esta configuración sea **permanente** puede hacerlo de la siguiente manera (esto a partir de pip 10.0)

```
$ pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip setuptools
```

O simplemente volviéndolo a [instalar](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) para obtener la última versión:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Es posible que quiera agregar los servidores y el proxy de confianza a su archivo de configuración.

`pip.ini` (Windows) o `pip.conf` (Linux)

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org
```

Comment: Hola eres un genio, ya resolvi el problema cambiando la configuración con $ pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip setuptools. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Excelente que te sirviera!!